# How do I reset Superset's db?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I've been testing stuff out with Superset and I think I corrupted my superset db. When I try to acess any chart i get this error:

[image: sqlalchemy error: dbs.perm not found]

I found a workaround to this problem, by searching with ag - the silver searcher which individual migration dropped the dbs.perm table, and using the command

`superset db downgrade <migration-id>`

on the migration prior to that one.

It's still not very clear to me which steps I would take as to completely reset the db safely.

I have the manual, dev installation since I'm working on customizing the code. Let's say I didn't have anything too important in the db, so I'm not afraid to loose tables, users, perms, etc.

I've found I have a superset.db in ~/.superset, but I don't think deleting that will be enough, right?

How can I reset Superset's db so as to make a clean db and start over? Can I do this without losing my Superset installation, or do I need to start over completely? In any case, can you guide me through it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need not to reinstall everything. Just remove the ~/.superset/superset.db file and take the backup of this file before removing it just in case you want to restore it. and then run the below commands. These commands will create another database file.

**Initialize the database**

`superset db upgrade`

**Create an admin user (you will be prompted to set a username, and first and last name before setting a password)**

```
$ export FLASK_APP=superset
$ superset fab create-admin
```

**Load some data to play with**

`superset load_examples`

**Create default roles and permissions**

`superset init`

Answer (score 2):

deleting `superset.db` in `~/.superset` should be enough and it's the more clean way to start over. Yet note that SQLLite is not a recommended DB engine for metadata and it's support should be completely removed on the future.

I also recommend using the docker-compose provided for testing/developing on Apache Superset

Comment: how do you reset db when you use docker-compose?

Comment: You just need to stop and restart the environment: `docker-compose down && docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up`